# how to process multiple files using java-xslt method?

Tags: java, xml, properties, xslt

I'm handling a task in which .java, .xslt, .bat and .properties files are involved.

Idea: to transform an xml-based file with extension tmx into a txt file, using xslt. Java is used as a kind of medium, connecting .properties and xslt. In the properties file, some parameters are appointed.

**xml**=abc.tmx
**xsl**=aaa.xsl
**output**=bbb.txt

The bat file acts as a launcher:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx768m -DentityExpansionLimit=2000000 -classpath . transformations.TMXTransform
```

As you can imagine I have to modify the properties file for each processing, with only one output generated, which is not ideal in terms of efficiency.

Now I'd like to have a better solution.

1. all files in a specific location with specific extension are detected automatically, say a.tmx, b.tmx, c.tmx....z.tmx
2. And with one double-click, corresponding txt output files with customizable filename,say a_output.txt, b_output.txt...z_output.txt) are generated to a specific location.

I suppose this is not difficult, but since I'm new to Java, I wonder if anybody can help.

BTW, directly using xslt is OK, too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not a Java wizard, I wonder whether you wouldn't be better off doing this in either Ant or XProc? Both are XML-based languages that allow you to control a sequence of transformations to selected files. It seems to me you're trying to invent a new property file syntax that's a simple control language for XSLT processing, and you don't need to, because several already exist.

Or another candidate would be xmlsh, a shellscript-like language for controlling XML processing tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the properties file in a different way. Create a custom properties file where each line represents a processing job where you specify all needed parameters. You program should read each line of the properties file, parse the parameters and process the file(s). With a single invocation your program can process as many files as you defined in your custom properties file. In order to read the properties file, use `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `StringTokenizer` or `String.split()` to parse the parameteres.

This is just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Per Michael Kay's suggestion, you could use a simple ANT build script, like this one, to transform all of your *.tmx files.

```
<project name="TranformXml" basedir="." default="TransformFiles">
    <target name="TransformFiles">
        <xslt basedir="${basedir}" 
            destdir="build" 
            style="transform.xsl" 
            includes="*.tmx"
            extension="_output.txt">
        </xslt>
    </target>
</project>
```